How to map a remote control in a Android app, made with Python?
I am making an application that will be used on a monitor that uses Android, the application is being developed with Python, with the use of the KivyMD and Kivy libraries, and is being compiled with Buildozer. Within the application I have some keyboard keys mapped to move in the application, in addition to the controller, since when used on a monitor, it will not work through a touch screen. Within the application you move between buttons, left or right. The problem is that once compiled and installed on the monitor, the controller does not work to move, using the buttons as I said, with the arrows (left, right, OK or Enter) as it would in other applications, instead with the keys of the keyboard if it does. I have tried to map the keycodes that the remote controls send by default, here is the code:
class MainApp(MDApp):
#Creacion e inicializacion
def build(self):
    Window.bind(on_key_down=self.on_key_down)
    self.theme_cls.theme_cls = "Dark"
    self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
    self.chrono = 0
    Builder.load_file('myapp.kv')
    return Ui()

This is the function that is executed at startup, and that matches the Android on_key_down function that detects which button has been pressed and matches it to my custom function, which is this:
def on_key_down(self, window, keycode, scancode, codepoint, modifiers):
    print("Key: ",keycode)
    #Movimiento
    if (keycode == 55 or keycode == 21 or keycode == 276):  # Tecla 7 (Izquierda) o tecla izquierda mando
        self.moveLeft()
    elif (keycode == 57 or keycode == 22 or keycode == 275):  # Tecla 9 (Derecha) o tecla derecha mando
        self.moveRight()
    elif (keycode == 56 or keycode == 66 or keycode == 13):  # Tecla 8 (Enter) o tecla enter mando
        self.enterButton()
    elif (keycode == 4 or keycode == 27): # Tecla atrás mando
        self.back()

(The coments are in Spanish ignore them)
Despite mapping everything, it does not work, it does not detect it since the print of the keycode that is to be debugged when the command is pressed does not print anything, that is, it does not get into the function. I have asked the factory and they told me that the app should, without the need to program anything extra, work with the remote. Furthermore, the compilation of buildozer is being carried out without any special permission from Android, with the buildozer.spec that is generated by default, only names and icons have been changed.
